# Images missing following php redirect

Tags: php, html

I have 3 pages:

```
room.php
room_poke.php
room_poke_checker.php
```

In the first page - I grab the page url by:

```
$pageurl=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

This is then passed to room_poke.php as a $_POST variable which, in turn, passes it on to room_poke_checker.php where it is used to redirect to the original room.php:

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="1; URL='.$url.'">';
```

It gets me there... but when I arrive back at room.php all images are missing (I get the 'missing image picture').

If I refresh the room.php it still has missing images but, if I click in the address bar and press 'enter' key then I'm back in business.

I can't figure out why!

How do I redirect to the page as it was intended to look?

Comment: any live url is there?

Comment: Do not use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` as page url.

Comment: OK @CharlotteDunois - I have hard-coded the url in the original page... but am still having issues. Thanks for responding though. :-)

Comment: @Mani - here is a link: http://www.enigmaeducation.co.uk/trial/room.php (You will have to refresh the page if you don't see a bumble bee... don't ask... click on it if you see him!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in how I was writing the url variable in my hidden values in the forms in each page.

I wasn't enclosing the `<?php echo $pageurl;?>` in " ".

I was writing:

```
<input name="pageurl" type="hidden" value=<?php echo $pageurl;?>/>
```

rather than:

```
<input name="pageurl" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pageurl;?>"/>
```

As soon as I rectified this it worked perfectly.